# How to create an MPxTransform node in Maya with a bounding box?

Tags: c++, transform, nodes, maya, bounding-box

In cpp, I am looking for the code to create an MPxTransform node in Maya with a bounding box. However my code does neither add a transform node in the outliner, neither creates a bounding box. What am I missing ?

.cpp file:

```
myClass::myClass() // Entry point: This one is executed
{
    myMPxTransformClass prox;
    MPxTransformationMatrix *transformMtrx;

    transformMtrx=prox.createTransformationMatrix();

// What is missing here to get the node registered in Maya and bounding box displayed ?

}

myMPxTransformClass::myMPxTransformClass()  // This one is executed
{
    MGlobal::displayInfo("MPx Initialized");

}

bool myMPxTransformClass::isBounded()  // This one is not called
{
    MGlobal::displayInfo("isBounded returned");

    return true;
}

MBoundingBox myMPxTransformClass::boundingBox()  // This one is not called
{
    MPoint p1,p2;
    p1=MPoint(-1,-1,-1);
    p2=MPoint(1,1,1);
    MGlobal::displayInfo("Bounding box returned");

    return MBoundingBox(p1,p2);
}
```

and the corresponding .h file

```
class myMPxTransformClass : public MPxTransform
{
public:
    myMPxTransformClass();
    virtual ~myMPxTransformClass() {};
protected:
    virtual MBoundingBox boundingBox();
    bool isBounded();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to write a plug-in, you need to implement 3 common function:

1. *initializePlugin*, called when the plugin is loaded
2. *uninitializePlugin*, called when the plugin is unloaded creator, that
   Maya calls to create a new instance of the object, such as create
   node
3. *creator*, that Maya calls to create a new instance of the object, such as `createNode`

This is an example code:

```
#include "include/HelloWorldCmd.h"
#include <maya/MFnPlugin.h>

void* HelloWorld::creator() { return new HelloWorld; }

MStatus HelloWorld::doIt(const MArgList& argList) {
  MGlobal::displayInfo("Hello World!");
  return MS::kSuccess;
}

MStatus initializePlugin(MObject obj) {
  MFnPlugin plugin(obj, "Chad Vernon", "1.0", "Any");
  MStatus status = plugin.registerCommand("helloWorld", HelloWorld::creator);
  CHECK_MSTATUS_AND_RETURN_IT(status);
  return status;
}

MStatus uninitializePlugin(MObject obj) {
  MFnPlugin plugin(obj);
  MStatus status = plugin.deregisterCommand("helloWorld");
  CHECK_MSTATUS_AND_RETURN_IT(status);
  return status;
}
```

Here you can find how more info about it:

http://www.chadvernon.com/blog/resources/maya-api-programming/your-first-plug-in/